# Does anybody know to make this layer style.?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography, photoshop-effects, layer-style

Can anyone tell me how can I get the attached text style? What setting I have to do? I want same text style. Same text style but different background and color

[image]
[image]

It would be awesome if someone can tell me what to say this type of text style? What they are called?

---

This what I have done. What I am missing there?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a colour gradient and a bevel, but this question is a bit broad as it stands. Maybe try building something and then edit your question to address where you get stuck or aren't happy with the results.

Comment: @Westside [link](http://imgur.com/a/QDtfZ}

Thats what I have done. What I am missing there?

Answer (score 1):

That is called a Bevel / Emboss effect. In Photoshop there's some built-in functionality for this found under Layer Styles. In Illustrator its a bit more complicated using the Effect > 3D Extrude and Bevel.

To get the exact effect above you'll have to really refine and play with these settings as it looks like there may be some additional work on it. Possibly a Glow or Plastic Filter added.

We also have a lot of questions on the topic: [GDSE Search: emboss](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=emboss)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a stroke to the outline of the text and apply your emboss effect there. As you can see in the sample, there is both high-light and shadow on the outline and only a gradient with touch of inner-glow on the actual type.
You also need to add a pillow effect underneath that is slightly offset into the lights direction. I’m sure there are multiple ways to achieve this.

[image]